# Is it now possible to tune classification model thresholds in tidymodels?

Tags: tidymodels

Does tidymodels now provide a means to tune classification model thresholds?  I believe this was slated as an upcoming feature in the Spring of 2020.  I looked around the tidymodels website, but have not seen a mention the feature.

Comment: Take a look at the [probably](https://probably.tidymodels.org/) package, especially the vignette on how to optimize probability thresholds. This package is still fairly immature so we are interested in feedback on what does/does not work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Julia says, there is an indirect method to do this.

We plan on making it a fully tunable parameter (like other parameters) but a few things have pushed this back but it is near the top of our development list.

Answer (score 1):

There's now an R package available, [probably](https://probably.tidymodels.org/reference/probably-package.html) (as part of the `tidymodels` ecosystem) that solves this problem.

In essence, we can change classification thresholds now like this:

```
hard_pred_0.75 <- lending_test_pred %>%
  mutate(
    .pred = make_two_class_pred(
      estimate = .pred_good, 
      levels = levels(Class), 
      threshold = .75
    )
  )
```

See [this example](https://probably.tidymodels.org/articles/where-to-use.html) for (reproducible) details.